# Why does an html with a single p bring up a scrollbar when body.height=100%

Tags: html, css

This html causes a vertical scroll to apear:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style>
        body, html {
            height:100%;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>some text</p>    
</body>
</html>
```

codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mykna

For my reasoning, the single p element does not cause the body to become larger than it is already by the 100% height setting. The truth however is, that the size of the p enlarges the body, its size is added. Why?

I tested this in current Chrome, FF, IE, all are (luckily) the same and bring up a vertical scrollbar, also Codepen shows the scrollbar.

**edit**

Removing height and setting min-height:100% and max-height:100% causes the behavior I expected, no scrollbar comes up. Which also makes me think, because min=max=100% should be the same as height=100%, in my simple mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing) and you could add `display:inline-block;` to `p` like this:

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJotf)**

```
p {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

To explain the margin collapsing behaviour, I've created a demo, in that demo the `p` tag has 50px margin top and bottom and the `body` has outline. As you can see the `p` tag margin collapsed and applied to the `body` and this forces the body to start from 50px below.

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wzheL7dz/)**

```css
body, html {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    outline: solid;
    outline-color: #F00;
    outline-width: 5px;
}
p {
    margin: 50px 0px; 
    background-color: #ADFF2F;
}
```

```html
<p>My Text</p>
```

Comment: excellent, that explains it, thank you! have to wait for marking it as answer.

Comment: I'm wondering WHY this behavior occurs, is it ever an advantage?

Answer (score 1):

`p` element has by default **margin-top** and **margin-bottom** value.

You could reset them by adding:

```
p { margin: 0; }
```

You could check: [Typical default display properties of `p` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html).